# Programmatically access Google Drive with Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

Is there a way to programmatically access a Google Drive folder without having to manually authenticate with OAuth for every session?

I've used [PyDrive](http://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/index.html) and managed to access the drive, but I still have to go through the manual browser OAuth access page every time I run my Python script.

Is there any way to grant permanent access to Google Drive with Python?

Answer (score 1):

OAuth usually works by granting you an access_token and a refresh_token. You can store these locally on the device to be used in a later session. Once the access_token expires, you can use the refresh_token to obtain a new pair of tokens.

This should work indefinitely as long as the granting service doesn't revoke them.